# Transitioning from shell to Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I want to know how I can convert this `shell script` to a `Makefile` and use `make all` to perform all the script's operations. I have two directories `pictures` and `thumbs`, where `thumbs` is empty before running the script and `pictures` contains some `.jpg` files. Finally, this is the `shell script` that I want to convert to a `Makefile`:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="thumbs"
if [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
    p=$(find pictures/|grep "jpg"|cut -d"/" -f2)
    for i in $p
    do
        m=$(ls -l pictures/$i | cut -d" " -f7)
        n=$(ls -l thumbs/$i | cut -d" " -f7)
        if [ "${m//':'}" -gt "${n//':'}" ] ;then
            rm thumbs/$i
            convert -thumbnail 100 pictures/$i thumbs/$i
        fi
    done
else
    find pictures/ |cut -d"/" -f2 | grep "jpg"| \
         awk '{system("convert-thumbnail 100 pictures/" $0 " thumbs/" $0)}'
fi
```

Comment: Put it in a shell script and run the shell script from Make

Comment: Do you mean you want to *rewrite* the script as a Makefile?  In that case, do you need to restrict yourself to the features defined for POSIX `make`, or would you be willing to depend on GNU `make`?

Answer (score 2):

From Makefile you can call a program.

Example

```
$ cat a.sh
echo From Makefile
$ cat Makefile
all:
    ./a.sh
```

Test :

```
$ make
./a.sh
From Makefile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the behavior of your shell code much more simply as a Makefile, at least if you are willing to rely on GNU `make`.  I interpret this to be what you're asking (modulo dependency on GNU make in particular).  This is a pretty functional rough cut:

```
THUMBS = $(patsubst pictures/%,thumbs/%,$(wildcard pictures/*jpg*))

all: $(THUMBS)

thumbs/%: pictures/% thumbs
    convert -thumbnail 100 '$<' '$@'

thumbs:
    mkdir -p '$@'

.PHONY: all
```

Notes:

- the `THUMBS` make variable gets set to a list of the thumbnail images you want to manage, based on expanding the shell glob `pictures/*jpg*` and replacing each occurrence of `pictures/` with `thumbs/`.

  - The pattern is chosen to match your shell code, but perhaps you really want something more like `$(wildcard pictures/*.jpg)`
  - File names with whitespace in them are going to present a tricky problem if you need to worry about them; file names with certain other special characters too, albeit a bit less so
  - the `patsub` and `wildcard` functions are GNU extensions
  - You could also merge the definition of `THUMBS` into the rule for `all`, and avoid a separate variable
- The rule for `thumbs/%: pictures/% thumbs` uses GNU-specific pattern rule syntax; this particular form is hard to express to POSIX `make`.
- The `thumbs` directory is created if absent, but errors will occur if there is an ordinary file of that name in the way
- `make all` (or just `make`) will update all out-of-date thumbnails; it does not rely on the same date comparison logic as the original script (which is a *good* thing)
- The `.PHONY` rule is just to be careful.  It prevents the existence of an actual file named "all" from interfering with `make`'s operation.

Comment: Very nice and the best solution.